# Open bootstrap modal and scroll to specific div based on Click Event (dynamic jquery)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, scroll, modal-dialog, click, bootstrap-modal

I have two or more click event based on this I want to open the Bootstrap modal. My problem was when I am open the modal using jquery and Inside modal I have suppose consider three section. In my click event also I have three same as the consideration in modal. For the instance I am going to click, now the bootstrap modal fired (opened) but its unable to get offset value of the particular section and also its not scrolling inside the modal. My only intention is based on the click need to scroll the bootstrap modal and show the particular section.

Here I have attached my Code of Bootstrap modal

```
<div class="modal fade modal5 in" id="myModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Testing</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal5-body">
            <div class="terms_condition section-1" data-section="section-1" id="section-1">
            <h3>Section One</h3>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="terms_condition section-2" data-section="section-2" id="section-2">
            <h3>Section Two</h3>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="terms_condition section-3" data-section="section-3" id="section-3">
            <h3>Section Three</h3>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
            </div> </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For My Click Event Html Code

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal5" data-section="section-1"> T &amp; C</a>
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal5" data-section="section-2"> T &amp; C</a>
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal5" data-section="section-3"> T &amp; C</a>
```

My Jquery should be like this

```
                $(document).on('show.bs.modal', '#myModal5', function(event) {
                    var section = $(event.relatedTarget).data('section');
                    var sectionOffset = $('#' + section).offset();
                     $('#myModal5 .modal5-body').animate({ 
                        scrollTop: sectionOffset.top
                    }, 1000);
                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a few elements to make this work:

- limit `.modal-body`'s height using CSS so it develops a scrollbar of its own, instead of having full height and relying on `<body>`'s scrollbar
- run your scrollTo fn on `shown.bs.modal`, not on `show.bs.modal`. `shown` is run after the modal was shown, `show` is run before the modal is opened.
- take into account current `scrollTop` of `.modal-body` (otherwise the second time you open the modal your `scrollTop` value will be wrong) and use [`.position()`](https://api.jquery.com/position/) instead of [`.offset()`](https://api.jquery.com/offset/).
- add a `min-height` to sections to allow sections to fill the modal height

Working example:

```js
$(document).on('shown.bs.modal', '#myModal5', function(event) {
  var section = $(event.relatedTarget).data('section');
  var sectionPosition = $('#' + section).position();
  $('#myModal5 .modal-body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#myModal5 .modal-body')[0].scrollTop + sectionPosition.top - 15
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
.modal-body {
  /* 200px is to avoid scrollbar on body 
   * 198px is min value for current footer + height
   */
  max-height: calc(100vh - 200px);
  overflow: auto;
}
.modal-body [class*="section-"] {
  min-height: calc(100vh - 215px);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal5" data-section="section-1">Section 1</a> |
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal5" data-section="section-2">Section 2</a> |
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal5" data-section="section-3">Section 3</a>

<div class="modal fade modal5 in" id="myModal5" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Testing</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="terms_condition section-1" data-section="section-1" id="section-1">
          <h3>Section One</h3>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="terms_condition section-2" data-section="section-2" id="section-2">
          <h3>Section Two</h3>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="terms_condition section-3" data-section="section-3" id="section-3">
          <h3>Section Three</h3>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hi, Tao thanks for the valuable answer and I will modify my code as the same above.